# Solution Verification: If $A$ and $B$ are block diagonal matrices with the same blocks, but in perhaps a different order, then $A$ and $B$ are similar

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

> If $A$ and $B$ are block diagonal matrices with the same blocks, but in perhaps a different order, then $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Here's my solution that I'd like checked, if possible. Let $\tilde{A}$ be the matrix formed by taking the blocks of $A$ into the ElemDiv version of the rational canonical form, and let $\tilde{B}$ be defined similarly. Then $A$ is similar to $\tilde{A}$ and $B$ is similar to $\tilde{B}$. So, the companion blocks of $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ are the same, except possibly in a different order, and by the ElemDiv version of the Rational Canonical Form, $\tilde{A}$ is similar to $\tilde{B}$.

Comment: Your solution is correct, if perhaps a bit of overkill. It suffices to find a permutation matrix $P$ such that $B = PAP^T$.

Comment: I had thought about that, but couldn't really come up with anything. How would you do it this way?

Comment: I cannot understand how you justify "So, the companion blocks of .." Passing to the RCF can amalgamate the blocks of the RCFs of the blocks of $A$ etc. @BenGrossmann 's remark on doing it directly is the way to go.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this problem. Now that you describe it this way, this solution does feel backwards in some sense. Would you be able to give some insight as to how to construct this permutation matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [any permutation can be expressed as a composition of transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions), it suffices to consider the case where $A$ and $B$ have the same blocks except that two of the blocks have been switched. Let $n_1,\dots,n_k$ denote the sizes of the blocks of $A$. Suppose that $B$ has the same blocks except that the $i$th and $j$th blocks of $A$ have been switched.
Let $I_n$ denote the identity matrix of size $n$. Let $n
 = n_1 + \cdots + n_k$ be the size of $A$ (and $B$). We construct $P$ by stacking $k$ "block-rows".

For all $p \notin \{i,j\}$, let the $p$th block-row be the $n_p \times n$ matrix given by
$$
\pmatrix{0 & \cdots & 0 & I_{n_p} & 0 & \cdots & 0},
$$
where each block-column has size $n_p$ and the $I_{n_p}$ occupies the $p$th block-column. Let the $i$th row be the $n_j \times n$ matrix given by
$$
\pmatrix{0 & \cdots & 0 & I_{n_j} & 0 & \cdots & 0},
$$
where each block-column has size $n_j$ and the $I_{n_j}$ occupies the $j$th block column. Similarly, let the $j$th row be the $n_i \times n$ matrix given by
$$
\pmatrix{0 & \cdots & 0 & I_{n_i} & 0 & \cdots & 0},
$$
where each block-column has size $n_i$ and the $I_{n_i}$ occupies the $i$th block column.

It can be shown that this matrix will satisfy
$$
B = PAP^T.
$$

Comment: This is very good. I feel like this question is one of those things that at first feels very convoluted, but as it turns out, this is probably the most natural way to construct $P$.

Comment: @Luna It might be helpful to look at an example. It's just difficult to explain the general pattern